# Issue with starting gala

Tags: gala

I've installed pantheon desktop over Ubuntu 18.04 but can't run it. Firstly I've tried to run it from LightDM just selecting it from drop-down menu, but after pressing "log in" it returns me back to LightDM and I don't find anything interesting in LightDM logs.

So I've tried to run pantheon manually on tty1:

```
startx /usr/bin/ghome-session --session=pantheon --debug 2> log
```

And in `log` I see this suspicious lines:

```
...
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): Starting app: /org/gnome/SessionManager/App1
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: starting gala.desktop: command=gala startup-id=10cbf37e055e8ae336157536606743993500000156620000
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: started pid:15813
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): GsmManager: RegisterClient 
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): GsmManager: Adding new client 10cbf37e055e8ae336157536606760263500000156620096 to session
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): uid = 1000
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): pid = 15809
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): exporting client to object path: /org/gnome/SessionManager/Client20
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): exporting dbus client to object path: /org/gnome/SessionManager/Client20
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): GsmStore: Adding object id /org/gnome/SessionManager/Client20 to store
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): GsmManager: Client added: /org/gnome/SessionManager/Client20
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: (pid:15813) done (status:127)
gnome-session-binary[15662]: WARNING: App 'gala.desktop' exited with code 127
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): Re-starting app: /org/gnome/SessionManager/App1
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): Starting app: /org/gnome/SessionManager/App1
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: starting gala.desktop: command=gala startup-id=10cbf37e055e8ae336157536606743993500000156620000
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: started pid:15818
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): GsmAutostartApp: (pid:15818) done (status:127)
gnome-session-binary[15662]: WARNING: App 'gala.desktop' exited with code 127
gnome-session-binary[15662]: DEBUG(+): Re-starting app: /org/gnome/SessionManager/App1
gnome-session-binary[15662]: WARNING: App 'gala.desktop' respawning too quickly
gnome-session-binary[15662]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

It seems there is some problems while running `gala`, but how can I know what exactly gone wrong? Is there some `gala` logs?

UPD1:
I've found an error in `journalctl -xe` output:

```
symbol lookup error: gala: undefined symbol: meta_screen_reorder_workspace
```

UPD2:
Well, as I understand, it is connected with this issue: https://github.com/alucryd/aur/issues/98, to work correctly we need a libmutter-2.0 version 2.39, but in ubuntu repos there is only 2.38, I don't know how to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've find out the problem: I've used `ppa:elementary-os/stable` repo that has issue with dependencies gala <-> libmutter.

So I've removed this ppa using `ppa-purge`:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

and installed instead `ppa:elementary-os/daily` + `ppa:elementary-os/os-patches`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo apt install elementary-desktop
```

Now everything works fine.