# Unable to login after 5.1 update

Tags: greeter

Today I've successful update my Elementary 5.0 system to 5.1.
After reboot I see brand new login screen, type my password and got login screen again.
I already tried to set runlevel from 5 to 3 and then launch "startx" command with no success. 
Please help

Comment: I've checked log files and found at syslog: gala: symbol lookup error: gala: undefined symbol: meta_screen_reorder_workspace

Comment: It seems that my issue is related: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21321/issue-with-starting-gala

Comment: I fixed this problem with the help of this website https://www.pc-prime.com/blog/unable-login-elementary-freya/ remove the .Xauthority file and install `pantheon-xsession-settings`

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login into the shell.

Now run `ls -lA | grep 'Xauth*'`. you'll see the line

```
-rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority
```

then you need to do `chown username:username .Xauthority` and try logging in (you may also need to do the same for for `.ICEauthority`).

Else, do `ls -ld /tmp`. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: `drwxrwxrwt`.

```
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
```

Else, you need to do `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` and check again.

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to reach the login screen again, and restart.