# Unable to Log In - Starting the session has failed

Tags: greeter, desktop-environment

let me give an intro to the mess I made, I wanted to uninstall the older version of Wine using synaptic manager and when I marked for removal there was an option for complete removal. I didn’t think about it and clicked okay and didn’t check back. 
So long story short, the elementary desktop, and a few other key packages were removed and now I can’t log back in as it says “unable to login” Starting the session has failed

I downloaded the 5.1 ISO thought I can do the upgrade but there’s no option for that either.

edit:
I installed and reinstalled the elementary-desktop from the terminal and I’m still getting the same error, I carried out an apt-update as well

Comment: how do you isntall it using terminal - via tty console screen or using **advanced options for elementary os** > Root shell ?

Comment: In My case it is opening with a Debian 8 wallpaper.. dont know.. why.. i did sudo apt install lightdm pantheon-greeter. Then run sudo dpkg --configure -a , then reboot but still the same problem exists.. all this happened when i tried to install real VNC server..

Comment: I had the same problem after I just run OS updates. I executed chown, but it didn't work. I still have a black screen. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

what I suggest you is to install via terminal lightdm and pantheon-greeter also.
`sudo apt install lightdm pantheon-greeter`. Then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to login after 5.1 update

[Unable to login after 5.1 update](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21487/unable-to-login-after-5-1-update)

terminal : ctrl+alt+F1
login
sudo -i
cd /home/username
chown username:username .Xauthority

because it is owned by root after the upgrade
ctr+alt+F7
login